# Return byRef from __call() and __callStatic() in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, pass-by-reference, specifications

The [specification of PHP's `_call()` and `__callStatic()` methods](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/14-classes.md#method-__call) specifies this syntax for the methods:

> public  function  __call  (  *$name*  ,  *$arguments*  ) *compound-statement*
>
> public static function __callStatic ( *$name* , *$arguments* ) *compound-statement*

It also clearly states that for both methods:

> The arguments passed to this method must not be passed byRef.

But there is no optional `&` in the syntax that allows returning byRef.

So am I right in assuming that because of this `_call()` and `__callStatic()` cannot **return** byRef?

**EDIT 1:** As far as I know, the syntax that would allow returning byRef would look like this:

> public  function  **&<sub>opt</sub>** __call  (  *$name*  ,  *$arguments*  ) *compound-statement*